# Error occured in my simple Android Web view Application

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, webview, android-app-bundle

import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    webviewsetup()
}

private fun webviewsetup() {
    wb_webview.webviewclient = webviewclient()


    wb_webview.apply {
        loadurl(url"https://fullmart.in/")
        settings.javaScriptenabled = true
        settings.safebrowsingenabled = true
    }
}
```

}

i get error in webviews and load url and even on settings could anyone help me in resolving

Comment: Please post your errors here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code its working fine.

```
//Add internet permission in manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


//activity.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wb_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>


//activity code
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var webView: WebView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
    webView = findViewById(R.id.wb_webview)
    webView.settings.apply {
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        safeBrowsingEnabled = true
    }
    webView.apply {
        loadUrl("https://fullmart.in/")
    }
  }
 }
```